# How can I create on Laravel Excel 3.0 populated with DB::select

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

[image: Sample Image]Need help... How can I create on Laravel Excel 3.0 / Maatwebsite 3.0 
populated with DB:select() ? I tried using Model to populate excel and it work...
Is their any way to make it work by not moving to Maatwebsite 2.1 ?

Comment: Can you show some example code of what you tried?

Comment: You should paste your code instead of a screenshot.